# Не срабатывает редирект

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Нужно сделать редирект:

```
http://example.com/newsarch_b.php?tx_ttnews[pointer]=2&cHash=023d9d50f6f0aff297816c3f53cd603b 
=> 
http://example.com/newsarch_b.php?tx_ttnews[pointer]=2
```

в htaccess написал следующее

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/newsarch_b\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tx_ttnews\[pointer\]=([0-9]*)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cHash=.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/newsarch_b.php?tx_ttnews\[pointer\]=%1 [R=301,L]
```

увы не сработало, пока более менее прогресс есть в этой записи:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (tx_ttnews%5Bpointer%5D=[0-9]+) [NC] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cHash=[^&]+ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^newsarch_b\.php example.com/newsarch_b.php?%1 [R=301,L]
```

при такой записи происходит редирект, но не совсем как мне надо 
вот так: 
http://example.com/newsarch_b.php?

```
tx_ttnews[pointer]=2&cHash=023d9d50f6f0aff297816c3f53cd603b 
=> 
http://example.com/newsarch_b.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

```
RewriteEngine On
# есть переменная bcHash
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bcHash=[^&]
# есть переменная tx_ttnews[pointer]. захватываем имя и значение состоящее из цифр
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \b(tx_ttnews\[pointer\]=\d+)
# переадресовываем с файла newsarch_b.php на него же, но в переменных остается только tx_ttnews[pointer]
RewriteRule ^newsarch_b\.php$ http://example.com/newsarch_b.php?%1 [R=301,L]
```